# Rxjs in nestjs - Observable subscription error

Tags: node.js, rxjs, observable, nestjs, behaviorsubject

I am newbie trying out rxjs and nestjs. The use case that I am currently trying to accomplish is for educational purpose. So I wanted to read a json file (throw an observable error in case of the file being empty or cannot be read) using the "fs" module. Now I create an observable by reading the file asynchronously, set the observer in the subject and then subscribe to the subject in the **controller**. Here is my code in the service

```
@Injectable()
export class NewProviderService {
    private serviceSubject: BehaviorSubject<HttpResponseModel[]>;
    // this is the variable that should be exposed. make the subject as private
    // this allows the service to be the sole propertier to modify the stream and
    // not the controller or components
    serviceSubject$:  Observable<HttpResponseModel[]>;

    private serviceErrorSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
    serviceErrorSubject$: Observable<any>;
    filePath: string;
    httpResponseObjectArray: HttpResponseModel[];
    constructor() {
        this.serviceSubject = new BehaviorSubject<HttpResponseModel[]>([]);
        this.serviceSubject$ = this.serviceSubject.asObservable();

        this.serviceErrorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
        this.serviceErrorSubject$ = this.serviceErrorSubject.asObservable();

        this.filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './../../shared/assets/httpTest.json');
    }
     readFileFromJson() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.exists(this.filePath.toString(), exists => {
                if (exists) {
                    fs.readFile(this.filePath.toString(), 'utf-8' , (err, data) => {
                        if (err) {
                            logger.info('error in reading file', err);
                            return reject('Error in reading the file' + err.message);
                        }

                        logger.info('file read without parsing fg', data.length);
                        if ((data.length !== 0) && !isNullOrUndefined(data) && data !== null) {
                            // this.httpResponseObjectArray = JSON.parse(data).HttpTestResponse;
                            // logger.info('array obj is:', this.httpResponseObjectArray);
                            logger.info('file read after parsing new', JSON.parse(data));
                            return resolve(JSON.parse(data).HttpTestResponse);
                        } else {
                            return reject(new FileExceptionHandler('no data in file'));
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    return reject(new FileExceptionHandler('file cannot be read at the moment'));
                }
            });
          });
    }


        getData() {
                 from(this.readFileFromJson()).pipe(map(data => {
                        logger.info('data in obs', data);
                        this.httpResponseObjectArray = data as HttpResponseModel[];
                        return this.httpResponseObjectArray;
                 }), catchError(error => {
                     return Observable.throw(error);
                 }))
                 .subscribe(actualData => {
                    this.serviceSubject.next(actualData);
                }, err => {
                    logger.info('err in sub', typeof err, err);
                    this.serviceErrorSubject.next(err);
                });
            }
```

Now this is the controller class

```
@Get('/getJsonData')
public async getJsonData(@Req() requestAnimationFrame,@Req() req, @Res() res) {

  await this.newService.getData();
  this.newService.serviceSubject$.subscribe(data => {
    logger.info('data subscribed', data, _.isEmpty(data));
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(data) && !_.isEmpty(data)) {
      logger.info('coming in');
      res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(data);
      res.end();
    }
  });
}
```

The problem I face is that I can get the file details for the first time and the subscription is getting called once > its working fine. On the subsequent requests

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\personal\Node\test-nest.js\prj-sample\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at Ser
```

and the endpoint /getJsonData results in an error. Could someone help me out. i believe the subscription is not getting properly after the first call, but not sure how to end that and how to resolve that

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't return your `Observable` directly from `getData()` but instead subscribe to `serviceSubject$`? Also, you don't need to work with `@Req` and `@Res` in your controller. Remove those parameters and return the `Observable` directly. Nest.js will handle the subscription.

Comment: the actual implementation will have to have a subject capable of returning the latest updated data and seems Behaviorsubject satisfies it. Also the suggestions seem not to make the subject available to the subscribers (the controllers) and hence made use of a variable

Comment: I also wanted to learn the response in handling the data emitted by the observable. So is nestjs auto handling the response closure once an observable is emitted? Not sure why it fails the above test case. I would give it a try by returning the observable directly, but wanted to know the reason for failure

Comment: Auto handling: "Nest will automatically subscribe to the source underneath and take the last emitted value (once the stream is completed)." I'll have a look at your code in more detail later.

Comment: @KimKern Thank you so much. Also I wanted to know if nestjs will handle this or is it something that is isloated to AxiosResponse type. The observable that I am producing is not an axiosresponse but a plain old observable. So wanted to know if by default,  nestjs tries to subscribe to the observable and produce a response and on the other hand , I manually try the same and that results in an error?

Comment: I think the problem is that you subscribe to the Observable to send the response but then you don't unsubscribe so it will try to send the response again when the next value is emitted. But since the response has already been sent you get the error

Comment: Nest would probably never send the response because your observable does not complete. I haven't tried it though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're subscribing to your `serviceSubject` in your controller. Every time a new value is emitted, it will try to send the response. This works the first time, but the second time it will tell you it can't send the same response again; the request has already been handled.

You can use the pipeable `first()` operator to complete the Observable after the first value:

```
@Get('/getJsonData')
public async getJsonData() {
  await this.newService.getData();
  return this.newService.serviceSubject$.pipe(first())
}
```

---

You want your `Observable` to be shared (hot), so that every subscriber always gets the same, latest value. That's exactly what a `BehaviourSubject` does. So you should not convert your `Subject` to an `Observable` when you expose it publicly because you will lose this desired behavior. Instead, you can just cast your `Subject` to `Observable`, so that internally it is still a subject but it will not expose the `next()` method to emit new values publicly:

```
private serviceSubject: BehaviorSubject<HttpResponseModel[]>;
get serviceSubject$(): Observable<HttpResponseModel[]> {
   return this.serviceSubject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to return the `Promise` directly to the controller. Here, you don't need an `Observable`. For the subscribers, you additionally emit the value of the `Promise` to your `serviceSubject`.

```
async getData() {
  try {
    const data = await this.readFileFromJson();
    this.serviceSubject.next(data as HttpResponseModel[]);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

In your controller you can just return the `Promise`:

```
@Get('/getJsonData')
public async getJsonData() {
  return this.newService.getData();
}
```

Comment: HI @KimKern I get an error while changing the method in the service from  returning an observable to a promise.  Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpResponseModel[]'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponseModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.t

Comment: Also since it for purely educational purpose, I was wondering what it might take for the observable to be properly emitted. Just curious , wanted to know what actually should be done to close the emission on time and start a new subscription

Comment: I also see that Observables have a lot more advantages over promise and hence persisting on trying to use that. Is there a way that I could convert it to an Observable<AxiosResponse<HttpRespomseModel[]>> instead of an observable<HttpResponseModel[]> , so that way when I return it, nestjs might automatically handle the response. and subscription closure?

Comment: The type error occurs because `readFileFromJson()` is not typed. See my edit, I've included a cast.

Comment: Yes, I also think rxjs is a great library. In your example, using an `Observable` just doesn't make much sense (at least for the controller) because it makes things unnecessarily complicated. But of course I understand the playing around aspect to get to know the library. :) I've added another answer that works with `Observables`, have a look.

Comment: I don't see how nest would handle an `AxiosResponse` differently than any other object. As far as I know, `AxiosResponse` is the return type when you make an http request with the `HttpModule`, but I'm not aware of any special handling by the nestjs controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to convert the cold observable (the one that I created) to a hot/warm observable might help to plugin to a single source and emit and complete its execution and maintain the last emitted data to any cloned values. So I make the cold observable to a warm observable using the publishLast(), refCount() operators, and I could achieve the single subscription and the execution completion of the observable. Here are the change I made to work.

This is the service class change I made

```
 getData() {
        return from(this.readFileFromJson()).pipe(map(data => {
                logger.info('data in obs', data);
                this.httpResponseObjectArray = data as HttpResponseModel[];
                return this.httpResponseObjectArray;
         }), publishLast(), refCount()
          , catchError(error => {
             return Observable.throw(error);
         }));
        //  .subscribe(actualData => {
        //     this.serviceSubject.next(actualData);
        // }, err => {
        //     logger.info('err in sub', typeof err, err);
        //     this.serviceErrorSubject.next(err);
        // });
    }
```

And this is the change I made in the controller

```
public async getJsonData(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
    let jsonData: HttpResponseModel[];
    await this.newService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      logger.info('dddd', data);
      res.send(data);
    });
}
```

Any answers that allow the observables to be first subscribed to subjects and then subscribing that subject in the controller is also welcome.

I found a great post on hot vs cold observables and how to make an observable subscribe to a single source and convert a cold, to a hot/warm observable - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html